# Excel VBA - Run macro if cell in range is clicked and selected

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I need a routine that can identify if a cell was clicked in a range and then run a macro. I've got this solved partly.

My problem is: 
I need to toggle a value whenever the cell is clicked, not whenever the cell is selected, so

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)    

If Not Intersect(Target, Range(testRange) Is Nothing Then
   'Cell was Clicked
End If

End Sub
```

does only work for me as long the cell is not selected.

What can I do? Is there a function to check if a mouse click was performed and the cell selected?

Answer (score 1):

Say we want to run a macro called `Hello()` when cell **B9** is clicked.

First select **B9** and insert a hyperlink to **B9**.

[image]

*(clicking this doesn't actually jump anywhere)*

Then in the worksheet code area insert:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Call Hello
End Sub
```